# Navigation rootViewController issue with HomeVC Sign out Button in Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, rootviewcontroller

I have home view controller with ENSideMenu for side menu and in home view controller i have sign out button. I have given ENSideMenu MyNavigationController as an is initial view controller in storyboard.

I want to show home first in app which is working fine but when i come from login to home then home is not responding.. once i sign out then again home is responding.

Here is my code:

in appdelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let userId: String? = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "Uid") 
    print("appdelegate userid \(userId)")
    if userId != nil{
        let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let homeVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
        self.window!.rootViewController = homeVC
    }
    return true
}
```

in loginButton in LogInVC:

```
    let saveUserId: Bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.set(Uid ?? "", forKey: "Uid")
                print("the userid is \(saveUserId)")

                if (Uid?.isEmpty)!
                {
                    print("login fail")
                }
                else{

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        let homeVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
                        let appDelagate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
                        appDelagate?.window??.rootViewController = homeVC
                    }
                }
```

in HomeVC:

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let nextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MakePaymentViewController") as! MakePaymentViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
    let indexPathHome = indexPath.row
    print("home collectionItem indexpath \(indexPathHome)")

}


 @IBAction func signOutButton(_ sender: Any) {
    print("signout tapped")
    KeychainWrapper.standard.remove(key: "Uid")
 }

  @IBAction func sideMenuButton(_ sender: Any) {
    print("in side menu")
    toggleSideMenuView()
 }
```

I have given ENSideMenu MyNavigationController as an is initial view controller in storyboard.

I need homeVc to respond after coming from login.
please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: anyone please help me here.

Comment: Can you provide some test app with your code (i.e. on github)? It's hard to understand what is the problem here.

Comment: @Michcio yes, please go through this, if u download then u can login with userid 8888888888 and password: test@1.. please help me here.  https://github.com/SwiftSamples/LoginHome

Comment: Provide me some steps to reproduce error, I don't know where I should click :)

Comment: @Michcio home is with collectionview, if we click in any item then it should go to makepaymentVC, in navigationbar green box for sidemenu, and red box for sign out.  u can login with sidemenu

Comment: @Michcio if i come from login to home then home is not responding... initially home is responding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using custom `MyNavigationController` with `HomeViewController` for navigation purposes - you already mention, that it is your initial view in storyboard. But... there are two other places, where you are loading `HomeViewController` without `MyNavigationController`:

1. `AppDelegate`

change loading `HomeViewController`:

```
let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
window?.rootViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyNavigationController")
```

2. `LoginViewController`

Change

```
let homeVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeVC)
```

to

```
let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let navigationController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyNavigationController")
```

---

Also, I have some advice for you:

1. Avoid `!` in your code - this is straight way to crash your app. There are lot of other ways to deal with optionals
2. Avoid catching strong `self` in closures (like in `LoginViewController`, when you are changing your view to HomeVC). This cause retain cycle, which leads to memory leak.
3. Remove all not needed `self`s - and when compilator tells you, that you need to add `self` - look at point 2) and add `weak self` instead of `strong`.
4. Remove compilator warnings - you already have 19 warnings, you can remove all of them in few minutes.

Comment: The solution is so perfect.. Thank you sooooo very much, you are the best, and definitely I'll follow your advice, actually in my original project 50 warnings.. definitely  i'll clear it.. once again thank you for your time to solve the above issue.